# handlebars get server data for helper functions

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js

I am setting-up the server `response` of a query to `couchbase` and want to use `handlerbars` to render the response data.

I understand that the best practice is to have my helper functions into a separate file and not be embedded in a `script` tag in my html file.

My question is what is the best practice or technique to pass the `data` from the server response to my hanldbars helper file to then be manipulated?

I am using `hapijs` on the server and `jQuery` on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Well I might be wrong, but following this example I found, it seems like you export the helper file like you would any other module with the `module.exports`

http://codyrushing.com/using-handlebars-helpers-on-both-client-and-server/

Answer (score 0):

According to the API documentation for `hapi` the helper file must export a single method with the signature `function(context).

> Helpers are functions used within templates to perform transformations
>   and other data manipulations using the template context or other
>   inputs. Each '.js' file in the helpers directory is loaded and the
>   file name is used as the helper name. The files must export a single
>   method with the signature function(context) and return a string.
>   Sub-folders are not supported and are ignored. Defaults to no helpers
>   support (empty path). Note that jade does not support loading helpers
>   this way.

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#route-options